# Determining pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, pointwise-convergence

Let 
$$f_{n}(x)=\frac{1-nx^2}{(1+nx^2)^2}.$$

Am I right in saying that $f_{n}(x)\not\rightarrow 0$ as $f_n(0)=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. For $x \neq 0$ the limit is $0$ and for $x=0$ it si $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the limit of the sequence $a_n = 1$ for all $n$ is $1$. So whatever $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n$ is, it is $1$ at zero.